# Powering LED tape from rechargeable batteries

Tags: batteries

I have some 12V LED tape that consumes 5W per m. I'd like to power a length of 5m of this from batteries. My initial thought was to use D-size NiMH rechargeable batteries. I know these output 1.2V, so I would need to use 10 in series.

If I were to purchase batteries with a capacity of 10000mAh, am I correct in my thinking that in ideal conditions the batteries would be able to power the LED tape for just under 5hrs?

My calculation is as follows:

10000mAh at 12V is 120Wh. The tape consumes 25W. Therefore 4.8hrs is how long it could last.

Comment: The mAh rating of the battery is when the terminal voltage has dropped to (quite possibly) below 1 volt per individual battery so, if you want an answer, link the data sheet of the D type and state by how much the terminal voltage can drop and still keep your circuit running as per your expectations.

Comment: ``am I correct in my thinking that in ideal conditions...`` Yes, the basic idea in your calculations is correct. Although in reality there are some more discrepancies as Andy mentioned above. When I do very quick estimates of battery life only in my head, I do the calculations that you've done and divide the result by 2. Then I get somewhere in the ballpark, probably without overestimating the battery life.

Comment: You'll be better off using a SLA battery.  One battery vs 10.  That's also only 2 connections vs 20.

Comment: @Andyaka told you that the actual voltage from your battery will not be constant over time. The Voltage falls off as the battery is depleted. How the falling voltage will affect the brightness and the current consumed by your LED tape is something you'll either have to get from a data sheet or by experiment. It's a calculus problem. The time before the LEDs go out altogether could be longer than 4.8 hours or could be less than 4.8 hours. The time before the LEDs become too dim to meet your needs likely will be a different number.

Comment: Depending on the method of current regulation, it might last much longer, but with gradually decreasing light output, if there are simply series resistors. As the voltage drops, current demand and light output rapidly decrease, since the *voltage differential* across a series resistor drops abruptly. (Consider, perhaps 9V LED drop and resistor limiting current to ~420 mA/m. When the battery drops to 10 V, only 1/3 that current flows, and at 9.5 V, 1/6.)